# Multiple source code blocks with the same name

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

## The context

Lately, I've been using the `=:noweb=` feature which has been of great help. Consider this minimal working example

```
* Using =std::cout=

#+NAME: a
#+begin_src cpp
std::cout << "a";
#+end_src

#+NAME: b
#+begin_src cpp
std::cout << "b";
#+end_src

#+begin_src cpp :noweb yes
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  <<a>>
  return 0;
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: a
```

## The problem

Now, let's suppose I create a new section within the same file with the following content.

```
* The =string= data type

#+NAME: a
#+begin_src cpp
std::string c = "AAA"
#+end_src

#+NAME: b
#+begin_src cpp
std::string c = "BBB"
#+end_src

#+begin_src cpp :noweb yes
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  <<b>>
  std::cout << c;
  return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

As you can see above, I've used the `a` and `b` names again as arguments to the `#+NAME` tag for the source code blocks present in this heading.

When evaluating the last source code block (the one from the `The =string= data type` section that contains `<<b>>`), it seems that `org` searches the source code block with name `b` and stop when one has been found. This causes a compilation error `'c' was not declared in this scope` because it is selecting the one from the `Using =std::cout` section. However, I would like `org` to select the one from the same heading.

Of course, I can create different names, but the problem is that the more source code blocks my file has, the harder it will be to select a name. I could use `cout-a` and `string-a` but then I won't be able to use those names again, so whenever I want to name a code block, I would need to look at all the names and think in a new one.

## The question

So, my question is: When having source code blocks with the same `+#NAME` tag, is it possible to make `org-mode` give higher priority to the ones from the same heading?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: In fact, `org-lint` complains with `Duplicate NAME` if you try to do that.